# probability of a number divisible by 5

Tags: probability

If the integers m and n are chosen between 1 and 100 , then a number of form $7^m$ + $7^n$ is divisible 5  , then what is its probability .

Not getting any start

Comment: Hint: how can the sum be divisible by 5? What does the last digit have to be? And now look at the last digit as you keep multiplying by 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we find $7^m$ where m lies b/w 1 to 100, we get last digit as 1,3,7,9.

Similarly for $7^n$. We get same last digits.

So we have now two sets $E = {1,3,7,9}$   and    $F = {1,3,7,9}.$

According to question sum of $7^m + 7^n$ divisible by 5.

So we have favourable cases = 4

Total cases = 4*4 = 16.

Probability P = 4/16 = 1/4.

Answer (score 2):

notice that the order of $7\bmod 5$ is $4$. since $4$ divides $100$ this means that every residue $(1,2,3,4)$ is equally likely.

We conclude the probability is $\frac{1}{4}$.(since no matter what the residue of $7^n$ is, the probability that the residue of $7^m$ will be the opposite is $\frac{1}{4})$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let $m\ge n$

$$7^m+7^n=7^n(7^{m-n}+1)$$

Now $7\equiv2\pmod5, 7^2\equiv-1$

So, we need $m-n=2+4a$ where $a(\ge0)$ is any integer

Now $1\le m\le100\iff1\le2+n+4a\le100$

For $n>0,2+2n+4a>2\ge1$

So, we need $n\le98-4a\le98$

So, the required probability  $$=\dfrac{\sum_{a=0}^{24}(98-4a)}{100^2}=\dfrac{\sum_{b=2}^{98}b}{100^2}$$